# Ĉu oni povas diri "bonaj novaĵoj" kvankam estas nur unu peco de informo?

Tags: plurals, expression

En la angla oni dirus ekzemple:

"I have good news. They've found seats for us on a different flight."

En Esperanto, ĉu oni simile uzas "bonajn novaĵojn" kiel esprimo aŭ ĉu oni devas pripensi ĉu estas unu afero aŭ pluraj kiujn oni anoncas?

Comment: Mi ŝatus aldoni, ke al miaj oreloj "peco de informo" sonas kiel anglismo. "Informo" estas kalkulebla en Esperanto, povas esti unu informo, du informoj, ktp.

Answer (score 9):

Mi kredas ke estus pli ĝuste diri nur “mi havas bonan novaĵon” se temas pri nur unu novaĵo. Estas multaj ekzemploj de tia uzo en Tekstaro:

*La Ŝtona Urbo*:

> Klemento informis min kun rideto, ke estas **bona novaĵo** por mi

*La Ondo de Esperanto*:

> Kaj jen **bona novaĵo** por tiuj, kiuj volus rigardi ĝin pli atente

*Ĉu li?*:

> lia unua ekmovo estis alkuri al Beatrico, por ke li estu la unua homo, kiu al ŝi anoncos la **bonan novaĵon**

Krome, mi kredas ke eĉ en la angla la vorto ne estas plurala kaj anstataŭe ĝi estas nenombrebla vorto kiel akvo. Ekzemple, oni ne povus diri *I have a new for you* kaj anstataŭe oni devus diri *I have a piece of news for you* (aŭ simple *I have news for you*).

Answer (score 2):

If you're tempted to say "I have a good piece of news for you" in English, then "mi havas bonan novaĵon" is certainly a good choice. Otherwise, there is a weak but clear tendency in Esperanto for *novaĵoj* to be plural.

Another use for singular *novaĵo* is "something new".

- jam de longe mi ne ricevis novaĵojn pri li

Mi rekomendas uzi ĝin plurale, sed oni vidas ambaŭ.

Answer (score 2):

Nu, unue mi rimarku, ke en Esperanto *peco de informo* povas signifi *parto de tuto de informo,* do *nekompleta informo:* en tiu ĉi ĉefe anglalingva demandejo ĉiuj ja rekonas la anglismon kaj komprenas, ke la signifo celata de la demandanto estas ***unu*** informo, sed estas grave substreki, ke iuj povus miskompreni.

Due, en mia denaska itala lingvo, kiel en Esperanto, malkiel en la angla, “novaĵo” estas nombrebla kaj pluraligebla. Mi ĉiutage diras “bona(j)n novaĵo(j)n” kaj en ununombro kaj en multenombro (nu plejofte nuntempe “**mal**bona(j)n novaĵo(j)n”, sed mi ne deflankiĝu...).

La malbona novaĵo estas, ke tian demandon oni malfacile traktas per serĉado en *Tekstaro* aŭ Guglo, ĉar ĉe ĉiuj rezultoj oni devus multe tro funde esplori la kuntekstojn por juĝi, kial ununombro aŭ multenombro estas uzata.

Do, en la itala, kiun regulon mi uzas? Ne nepre, ĉu temas pri unu aŭ pluraj informoj: estas pli subtile ol tio. Mi uzas ununombron se mi volas anonci unu grandan, specifan, unuarangan novaĵon. Mi anoncas “bonajn novaĵojn” pli ĝenerale, ne nur kun pluraj, sed eĉ kun nur unu informo, se ĝi estas malpli grava, malpli difinita, malpli specifa... “Bona novaĵo” estas “mi aĉetis domon!”. “Bonaj novaĵoj” estas ”jes ili ŝajnas emaj eble vendi domon je favora prezo”. Mia uzado en Esperanto certe paŭsas la italan. Se tio okazas ankaŭ kun multaj simil-denask-lingvaj esperantistoj, jen tio klarigas, kial *there is a weak but clear tendency in Esperanto for* novaĵoj *to be plural,* kiel skribis Tomaso: novaĵoj estas nebulaj, iom necertaj, bagatelaj multe pli ofte ol bone difinitaj, klare elstaraj kaj do singularigeblaj.

Do, jen la bona novaĵo: en kazo de dubo, vi povas ĉiam uzi pluralon. Uzu singularon kiam vi certas, ke unu informo plej elstaras.

Answer (score 1):

Fakte *news* estas singularo malgraŭ la `s` (`The news is ...`), ĉar la angla ne distingas nombrecon pri *news*. Eble kongrue al ĝermanaj lingvoj `something new` -> *new+s* (ned. *nieuws*, germane ~ *Neues*) - kun "genitiva" `s`.

En Esperanto kun -aĵ temas pri io konkreta (*news item*), *novaĵo/novaĵoj* - kun pluralo. En via kazo singularo: **novaĵo**